# Jquery mobile slider events not firing

Tags: jquery, jquery-mobile, jquery-slider

I want to alter the proportions of a DIV using a jquery slider (on a mobile device). The code is pretty simple and works on a JS Fiddle ( http://jsfiddle.net/gsjBC/1/ ) but not on a normal html page for some reason. Can anyone help me identify why not?

Here is the html

```
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN"     "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head>
    <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8" />
    <title>Testing</title>


    <link rel="stylesheet" href="http://code.jquery.com/mobile/1.2.0/jquery.mobile-1.2.0.min.css" />
    <script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.8.2.min.js"></script>
    <script src="http://code.jquery.com/mobile/1.2.0/jquery.mobile-1.2.0.min.js">      </script>
</head><body>

<div data-role="fieldcontain"><input type="range" name="slider" id="slider" value="60" min="0" max="100" /></div>

<script>
$("#slider").change(function() { 
sliderValue =    $(this).val();$("#proportion").width(sliderValue*3);
$("#proportion").height(300-sliderValue*3);});
</script>

<div id="proportion" style="border:1px solid #ccc; width:150px; height:150px;" /></div>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Put:

```
$("#slider").change(function() {
```

In

```
$(document).ready(function() {
// here
});
```